# how Jooq distinct or countDistinct more than one column

Tags: java, mysql, distinct, aggregate-functions, jooq

I found that the distinct function in the Factory class only accepts one parameter

```java
public static AggregateFunction<Integer> countDistinct(Field<?> field);
```

and there is no function like `distinct(Field... fields)`

I want to to express a SQL statement like this:

```sql
select c1, count(distinct c2,c3) from t1 group by c1;
```

PS: there is a non-dsl api: `SelectQuery.setDistinct(true)`, but it will "distinct" all columns, which is not what I want.

Comment: Can you please tag this question with the relevant database that you're using? E.g. is it MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is interesting. To my knowledge, this should not be possible in SQL. The SQL:2008 standard specifies

```
10.9 <aggregate function>

Format
<aggregate function> ::=
      COUNT <left paren> <asterisk> <right paren> [ <filter clause> ]
    | <general set function> [ <filter clause> ]

<general set function> ::=
  <set function type> <left paren> [ <set quantifier> ]
    <value expression> <right paren>
```

There is no room for comma-separated argument lists, with or without the `DISTINCT` set quantifier. This is implemented correctly in Oracle:

[image]

Yet, MySQL seems to allow for this non-standard "convenient syntax":

> ```
> COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])
> ```
>
> Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr values.

(taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

To answer your question, this is currently not possible in jOOQ, although I filed [#1728](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1728) for future support. Currently, you can work around this by writing your own multi-argument aggregate function support:

```java
Field<Integer> myCount = Factory.field(
  "count(distinct {0}, {1})", Integer.class, c2, c3);
```

See the relevant Javadoc for the [`Factory.field(String, Class<T>, QueryPart...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/Factory.html#field%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20org.jooq.QueryPart...%29) method for details

#### This is now implemented in jOOQ 2.6:

You can write

```
Field<Integer> count = Factory.countDistinct(c2, c3);
```

See the Javadoc for the [`Factory.countDistinct(Field...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/Factory.html#countDistinct%28org.jooq.Field...%29) method, for details

Comment: I found it almost a impossible thing to let jooq to support so many databases and so many exception! Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @user1511236: The feature is added on [GitHub for version 2.6.0](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/commit/172d2e80fae95d1c8f8c899100ef891b64a6ab1d). Note that this syntax seems to be only supported by HSQLDB and MySQL